# Refresh_token not there in json response in google oath

Tags: json, python-2.7, google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth

i am trying to some work with youtube apis, the code to fetch refresh_token looks like this:

```
import requests
params={"code":"something",
"client_id":"something",
"client_secret":"something",
"access_type":"offline",
"redirect_uri":"https://localhost",
"grant_type":"authorization_code",
 }
endpoint="https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"
data=requests.post(endpoint,params)
if data.status_code==   200:
    print "data recieved"
    print data.content
else:
    print data.status_code , "status_code"
    print data.content
```

and the response json is :

```
data recieved
{
 "access_token": "something",
 "token_type": "Bearer",
 "expires_in": 3580
}
```

There is no refresh_token in reponse, `access_type:offline` should have made it return refresh_token.

I have tried

```
prompt=consent
```

in url .. and still no luck ..

any  help would be appreciated

Comment: Try and remove its access https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions?pli=1  sometimes it only gives you the refresh token the first time you authenticate.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the advice but this didn't solved it .. i cleared this list on the above link and still no luck

Comment: next guess:  approval_prompt=force

Comment: :( nope, it ll be a pain asking for the user to authenticate every time, there should be a solution for this or maybe i am missing something.

Comment: have you tried checking the code in the Python client library.  https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client